# Suitable XML schema for Marshaller setSchema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm having a hard time figuring out the correct schema (to validate the structure and data types) of simple [classes](http://pastebin.com/wqhbSrJK). For example, I could get answer for `Employee` class with `schemagen` (supplied with JDK), but still could not get it to work for `HumanResources`.

I'm trying to serialize collection of `Employee` class instances to XML. For that, I have created class `HumanResources`, that contains a list of `Employee` class elements. Example:

```
    ArrayList<Employee> ems = getTestData();
    HumanResources hm = new HumanResources(ems);
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(HumanResources.class);

    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setSchema(sf.newSchema(new File("src\\server\\HumanResources.xsd")));
    marshaller.marshal( new JAXBElement<HumanResources>(
            new QName(null, "HumanResources"), HumanResources.class, hm), os);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example of how to create an XML schema using the JAXBContext:

First you must create a class that extends javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver.

```
public class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {

    public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(suggestedFileName);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        result.setSystemId(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then use an instance of this class with JAXBContext to capture the generated XML Schema.

```
Class[] classes = new Class[4]; 
classes[0] = org.example.customer_example.AddressType.class; 
classes[1] = org.example.customer_example.ContactInfo.class; 
classes[2] = org.example.customer_example.CustomerType.class; 
classes[3] = org.example.customer_example.PhoneNumber.class; 
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes);

SchemaOutputResolver sor = new MySchemaOutputResolver();
jaxbContext.generateSchema(sor);
```

For more information see:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema